# Apex Class - System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am new to classes and triggers. I'm attempting to run a simple query for a custom object in Salesforce but each time I try to move my class (along with the test) over to production, I get "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Stack Trace: Class.CloneListTest.testCloneListControllerFive: line 150, column 1". I've tried following suggestions I found on Google but nothing seems to work (probably because I am doing something wrong.)

**Class:**

```
   public class FindPT {
      @AuraEnabled
         public static List<PT_Tracker__c> getAllAccounts(){
          return [Select Id,Name ,Running_Total_Warning__c,Eligible__c,Employee__c,Running_Total__c, Accrual_Rate__c,Running_Balance_of_Accrued_Hours__c,Running_Balance_of_Approved_Hours__c from PT_Tracker__c Where Employee__c = :UserInfo.getUserID()] ; 
         }
    }
```

**Test:**

```
@isTest public class TestFindPT1 {
static testMethod void testAccountList ()
{ List<PT_Tracker__c> pt_trackers = new List<PT_Tracker__c>(); 
 for (Integer count = 0; count < 50; count++) 
 { pt_trackers.add(new PT_Tracker__c (Employee__c = '00561000003gg9K')); } 
 insert pt_trackers;

 Test.startTest(); 

  try{
 FindPT.getAllAccounts();       
}
    catch(Exception e){
}

 Test.stopTest();

 PT_Tracker__c ACC = [select employee__c from PT_Tracker__c LIMIT 1]; 
 System.assertEquals ( String.valueOf(ACC.employee__c) , '00561000003gg9K'); 

}
}
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted looks unrelated to the error. Nothing here says "CloneListTest" (that might be something that's called indirectly from a trigger but with name like that I suspect it's another unit test).

Don't deploy anything, go to production and compile all classes, run all tests (if you have some managed packages installed you don't have to run them, you care only about your own code). If all passes - the problem is with what you're trying to deploy. If it fails - you have to inspect failing test. Maybe some business logic changed. Maybe there's a new required field or validation rule, somebody did it straight in production and you're just a victim. Or maybe you don't have some security permissions but another user that was doing deployments before can make it happen.

Comment: I followed your advice and found the culprit (a validation rule on an object we don't even use anymore). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah, a slap on the wrist for admins that add new validation rules or required fields straight to prod, "what could possibly go wrong"... Glad I could point you in right direction.